# How can I dump only outgoing IP packets in tcpdump?

Tags: linux, ip, tcpdump, arp

I'm dumping outgoing traffic. I only want TCP and UDP packets destined outside my LAN, nothing else. I just used the following filter with tcpdump:

```
ip and (tcp or udp) and (not icmp) and src host myIPAddr and not dst net myNet/myNetBits and not ip broadcast
```

But I captured the following packet:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 00:1e:4a:e0:9e:00
  type      = 0x806
###[ ARP ]###
     hwtype    = 0x1
     ptype     = 0x800
     hwlen     = 6
     plen      = 4
     op        = who-has
     hwsrc     = 00:1e:4a:e0:9e:00
     psrc      = X.X.X.X
     hwdst     = 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst      = Y.Y.Y.Y
###[ Padding ]###
        load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What happened here? I thought I was dumping *only* IP packets.

Answer (score 7):

Set filtering on your host as a source:

```
tcpdump src <YOUR_IP>
```

Comment: This does show outgoing traffic for routed packages.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your dump you received **ARP** packet with IP protocol type (i.e. **ptype = 0x800**).  You should filter out also ARP packets `and (not arp)` and that should cleanup your dump.  I think if you look at the tcpdump code you will find the reason why it keeps also these specific ARP packets (but since IP uses these packets for network resolution I guess these ARP packets are considered part of IP by tcpdump).

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried to add that condition to my filter and I still get packets like the following:

`###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 00:1e:4a:e0:9e:00
  type      = 0x806
###[ ARP ]###
     hwtype    = 0x1
     ptype     = 0x800
     hwlen     = 6
     plen      = 4
     op        = who-has
     hwsrc     = 00:1e:4a:e0:9e:00
     psrc      = X.X.X.X
     hwdst     = 00:00:00:00:00:00
     pdst      = Y.Y.Y.Y
###[ Padding ]###
        load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: I could easily filter out non-IP packets after dumping, but I don't understand why it just won't work with a simple filter like the one above.

Comment: Well ARP is used by IP as stated in: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc894.txt.  You can try also filter `not ether proto arp` to try to remove arp packets (I have not looked at the tcpdump code in long time so I cannot remember the exact filtering approach)

Comment: `not ether proto arp` doesn't work, even though it looks correct to me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Try: `not ether proto \arp` . From what I recall older versions of tcpdump did not like *arp* and wanted *\arp* as **arp** is a keyword